# Can someone please explain me this?

Tags: php

I am taking one number from the form in PHP
and when looping through the number of digits using the STRLEN (number) function, and printing the modules of the number by 10, I am getting a weird result which I am not able to understand, can you please explain me this.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="number">Enter the number</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['number']))
{
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $sum=0;$rem=0;
    for($i=0;$i<=strlen($num);$i++)
    {
        echo $rem = $num%10;
    }    
} 
?>
```

I was trying to find the sum of digits and found this result when just trying to echo what the modules of number will show

Comment: Can you explain what result you are getting versus what you expected?

Comment: At a quick glance, you never do anything with `$i` or `$rem`. In each iteration of the loop, you're just echoing out the result of `$num%10`, which will be the same each time.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are required to, among other things, provide a meaningful title which actually relates to your problem ("help me" is not meaningful...everyone posts because they want help!!), and also, when describing a problem with your code, you need to explain fully what you expected to happen, and what  actually happens - preferably with actual sample data rather than just descriptions. It's then a **lot** easier to understand. Remember we cannot see your screen or read your mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="number">Enter the number</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['number']))
{
    $num = (int)$_POST['number'];
    $sum=0;$rem=0;
    while ($num > 0) {
      $rem = $num % 10;
      $sum += $rem;
      $num = $num / 10
   }    
} 
?>
```

As far as i understand your problem, here it needs to be done with the sum of the digits, so the above code which will help you to find the sum of the digit.